# How can I build an ios executable using Qt 5.2 and qmake from the commandline?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt, qt5

I have been using Qt on desktop platforms for years (since Qt3).  Having been doing quite a bit of mimimal QtQuick/QML stuff recently,  I'm interested to try out Qt5.2's newfangled ios support (which would be my first venture into anything "mobile").  I'm having trouble figuring out how to build anything but the usual MacOS apps though.

I have:

- a mid 2012 MacBookPro with MacOS 10.8.5
- xcode 5.1 installed, and the commandline tools updated
- Qt 5.2.1 http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/qt-opensource-mac-x64-ios-5.2.1.dmg installed from "Qt 5.2.1 for iOS (Mac, 909 MB)" link at http://qt-project.org/downloads

For starters, I'll settle for something really simple; this `test.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
CONFIG += debug
QT += core gui quick
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
  QQuickView view;
  view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml"));
  view.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

(of course there's also a `test.qml` but it's irrelevant here) and then I try and build it with

```
qmake -spec macx-xcode test.pro
```

which gets me a `test.xcodeproj/` created, and then

```
xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

builds a bunch of stuff... but just yields a MacOS app, albeit one which runs as expected on the Mac with `./Debug/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test`.

The `qmake` used is definitely the one from the "Qt 5.2.1 for iOS" install.

So, **what do I do to change in the above to get ios executable I can run with xcode's ios simulator** (including, ideally, launching the simulator from the commandline) **?**

Haven't had much luck googling for solutions; everything I've found seems to just say "and then you open the xcodeproj file in xcode and build it".  I've tried that and (once I figured out the project needed to be added to a workspace) it just builds me a MacOS app too, which leads me to suspect the qmake needs to be doing something, but if it was as simple as a different `-spec` argument I'd have thought I'd have discovered that.  (BTW, I've never used xcode before and would rather interact with whatever it brings to ios building via commandline & scripting if at all possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix turns out to be simple:

Use the `5.2.1/ios/bin/qmake` instead of the `5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake` one.

I was enlightened regarding this important detail via the [Qt Forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/40514/).

Haven't discovered how to do a complete commandline workflow to the iOS simulator yet, but launching it from xcode is simple enough.